# Setting the color of the Vuetify app-bar extension

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to change the color of the v-app-bar extension so it is a different color to the v-app-bar. There seems to be nothing in the documentation but I imagine such a simple change cant be that difficult and many people would want to make this change. I have tried changing it with CSS to no avail.

```
  <v-app-bar
    app
    extensionHeight="35px"
    class="light-blue darken-4 px-2"
  >

    // This is the part I want to appear a separate color.
    <template 
      v-slot:extension
      class="extension-style"
    >
      <v-tabs align-with-title>
        <v-tab>Browsing History</v-tab>
        <v-tab>Todays Deals</v-tab>
        <v-tab>Your Store</v-tab>
        <v-tab>Gift Cards</v-tab>
        <v-tab>Registry</v-tab>
        <v-tab>Sell</v-tab>
      </v-tabs>
    </template>

  </v-app-bar>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I struggled with this for a while, but eventually succeeded in making the change through CSS because I couldn't find any help in the Vuetify Docs

In my .vue file where the v-app-bar is defined I added the following lines:

```
<style>
div.v-toolbar__extension {
  background-color: green;
}
</style>
```

I determined "div.v-toolbar__extension" was the correct element by inspecting the page through chrome, if you've defined a class or id, the name may be different.

Note: My editor automatically applied "scoped" to the "style" section. This tripped me up for a while as the CSS had no effect until I removed the scoped keyword.

Edit: If you wish to keep the "scoped" styling, the alternative would be to use:

```
<style scoped>
/deep/ div.v-toolbar__extension {
  background-color: green;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for thanks. I'm surprised the option is not included.